# Does Java support StartTLS with LDAP referrals

Tags: java, ldap, starttls, referrals

We have an Active Directory server that uses referrals and we want to talk to it using the JNDI Java client library. We also want to use StartTLS to encrypt the connection.

I understand StartTLS can be done using `javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext#extendedOperation(ExtendedRequest)`

And that referrals can be followed when `java.naming.referral` is set to `follow`. However what I could find no documentation for is whether StartTLS is applied to the referrals as well.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/ext/starttls.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/referral/jndi.html

Comment: Why not use LDAPS? There is no advantage of statTLS with Microsoft Active Directory

Comment: Mostly because we only have SRV records for site awareness only for LDAP but not LDAPS.